# can we trigger an event on cell phone calls using mobile websites?

Tags: events, mobile, web, phone-call

Can we trigger an event on cell phone calls using mobile websites created using java and spring MVC?

Basically we need to trigger some events when cell phone receives a call.

Is it possible or do we need to use some native apps to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need an app to do that, since a WebSite has no access to device APIs.

What you can do, is to create an App based on Web technologies, and use a Framework like Phonegap to subscribe to events like when your app gets closed or is going to the background.